# Turning on assertions while compiling with Haskell's stack build system

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am using Stack 9.0 as my Haskell build system for my project.

I've just noticed that when I compile my Haskell project with Stack, all assertions are switched off. By contrast while doing "normal" GHC builds at the command-line, assertions are turned on by default unless explicitly switched off with the `-fignore-asserts` flag ([link](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.0.0/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:assert)).

For instance this simple main function fails to throw an assertion error

```
import Control.Exception.Base

main :: IO ()
main = assert (1==2) $ print "Hello World!"
```

How do I edit the .cabal file of my project to turn on assertions? Currently inside my .cabal file I see the following ghc options

```
 ghc-options: -threaded -rtsopts -with-rtsopts=-N
```

which is strange because assertions have not been explicitly turned off within this list.

EDIT:

I have `Version 1.1.2 x86_64 hpack-0.14.0` after running `stack --version`. In particular, I am using `stack lts 9.0` with `ghc 8.0.2`

Comment: Which version of stack do you have `stack --version`? And which ghc?

Comment: @epsilonhalbe Please see edit.

Comment: At some point, cabal decides to add `-O` to the `ghc --make` command (I've confirmed this on my machine with stack 1.1.3 and cabal 1.24.2.0). As the docs state, this also causes assertions to be turned off. I'm not actually sure why - maybe somebody more knowledgeable will show up and explain it. You can get around it by adding `-fno-ignore-asserts` to `ghc-options` (or `-O0` I'm guessing, but that probably would have undesired side-effects).

Comment: @user2407038 Hmm I don't see any difference even after adding the `-fno-ignore-asserts` flag. How do you see the flags used to build a particular executable, so that I can check if assertions are being disabled?

Comment: Add `-v` (or `-v2` or `-v3`) to the `ghc-options` field. But I've also verified this behaviour (that is, `stack build`, adding the `-fno-ignore-asserts` flag and then `stack build`) doesn't actually take affect. Even `stack build --reconfigure --force-dirty` doesn't work! I had to delete the `.stack-work` directory. (This one definitely looks like a bug, but keep in mind that stack-1.1.2 and 1.1.3 are very, very outdated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try passing in the --fast flag, which will disable optimizations (via `--ghc-options -O0`) and allow assertions to run.